# Can I run multiple (70) SQL files with one executable script?

Tags: sql, r, ssms

I have 70 SQL queries that I am managing through Git/Stash.  In order to facilitate this, I've split each query into an individual SQL file.  Before the split, the code worked by declaring all of the variable with the first query and running them in total as a whole.  The queries all together total about 10k lines.

I would like to write a script (willing to learn) that would allow me to connect to the correct database, declare some universal variables, and then call all of the different files in a folder with the declared variables.

My initial thought is to use R and the RODBC package, but want to make sure I'm on the right path before proceeding. Is this possible and should I refine my approach?

Comment: You can easily loop over files with R, and I use the RODBC package to create and load data from SQL databases all the time, so I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes you can, and R isn't required - I'm guessing you picked R because that's the language you know. Personally I'd go with PowerShell because it's already on Windows so I wouldn't be adding extra dependencies. But providing a working script for you is beyond the scope/intent of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script in SQLCMD mode (in SSMS you can enable it from Query/SQLCMD Mode).

The main script defines the global variable `@msg` and runs the other scripts sharing the variable with them:

```
:setvar path   "F:\scripts"

:on error exit

SET XACT_ABORT ON

declare @msg nvarchar(100) = 'This is a global variable defined in the main script.'

:r $(path)/"script_1.sql"
:r $(path)/"script_2.sql"
```

The two scripts files contain simple select statements that use the global variable `@msg`.

script_1.sql:

```
select @msg + ' And this comes from script_1.sql' as RESULTS_FROM_SCRIPT_1
```

script_2.sql:

```
select @msg + ' And this comes from script_2.sql' as RESULTS_FROM_SCRIPT_2
```

This is the result:

[image]